# When $e^A$ is a stochastic matrix?

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Assume some square matrix $A$. My question is, under what "necessary" conditions on $A$, is $e^{A}$ a stochastic matrix? For sufficiency, I know that if $A_{i,j}\geq0, \,\forall i\ne j$ and each column of $A$ sums up to $0$, and $A_{i,i}\geq -1$, then $e^A$ is stochastic. That is because

$$
e^A = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-1}}{k!} (\mathbb{I} + A)^k
$$
(note that putting those conditions $A$ implies $\mathbb{I}+A$ is a transition matrix, and the expression above is saying $e^A$ could be thought of a convex combination of $(\mathbb{I}+A)^k$'s.)

However, what is some necessary conditions? (By stochastic I mean, each column sums up to $1$ and all elements are positive).

Comment: I just want to point out that for any given transition matrix $A$, then $e^{tA}$ is a stochastic matrix, since it describes the Markov transition dynamics ${d\pi \over dt} = A\pi$

Comment: You can deduce necessary conditions by looking at $\frac{1}{t}(id-e^{tA})$ as $t\to 0$.

Comment: Well, there is no assumption on $e^{tA}$..